# Shuffle elements in list with same names

Tags: r

I have a large list of lists of matrices. The format can be seen here: [image: Input Data]

These are 50 matrices but divided into sublists and ordered. What I need is one list of 50 matrices in random order while keeping the names which are characters 0-10. Example:

```
0: [1:28, 1:28] 0 0 0 ...
5: [1:28, 1:28] 0 0 0 ...
3: [1:28, 1:28] 0 0 0 ...
0: [1:28, 1:28] 0 0 0 ...
8: [1:28, 1:28] 0 0 0 ...
8: [1:28, 1:28] 0 0 0 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a dataset example I don't know if this runs but here it goes.

```
set.seed(3694)
inx <- sample(names(trainData), 50, TRUE)

tmp <- lapply(inx, function(i){
    lst <- trainData[[i]]
    mat <- lst[[sample(seq_along(lst), 1)]]
    list(i, mat)
})

result <- lapply(tmp, `[[`, 2)
names(result) <- sapply(tmp, `[[`, 1)
rm(tmp)
```

**EDIT.**
Tested with the data by CPak, a bug in the names of the result was corrected. It now seems to do what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

What about using sample(...)? Running it second time gives you new permutation:

```
> a = list('0'=list(2,3),'1'=2,'2'=3)
> a
$`0`
$`0`[[1]]
[1] 2

$`0`[[2]]
[1] 3


$`1`
[1] 2

$`2`
[1] 3

> sample(a,length(a))
$`1`
[1] 2

$`2`
[1] 3

$`0`
$`0`[[1]]
[1] 2

$`0`[[2]]
[1] 3


> sample(a,length(a))
$`2`
[1] 3

$`1`
[1] 2

$`0`
$`0`[[1]]
[1] 2

$`0`[[2]]
[1] 3
```

Comment: If you want to have the same random order, you need to initialize random number generator before calling sample: set.seed(42); sample( ... )

Comment: I believe you should include argument `replace = TRUE` since in the question the OP says she wants to sample 50 out of a list of 10 elements.

Comment: I think this only shuffles the lists inside of the large list. The elements within lists are still ordered.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Data

```
data <- lapply(1:10, function(i) lapply(1:5, function(j) matrix(1:(28*28), nrow=28)))
names(data) <- 1:10
str(data)
# List of 10
 # $ 1 :List of 5
  # ..$ : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  # ..$ : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  # ..$ : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  # ..$ : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  # ..$ : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ 2 :List of 5
  # ..$ : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  # ..$ : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  # ..$ : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  # ..$ : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  # ..$ : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # etc
```

`purrr::flatten` your list

*EDIT* If each list has a different length, you can use `names(result) <-
 rep(1:length(data), times=(lengths(data)))` instead

```
library(purrr)
result <- flatten(data)
names(result) <- rep(1:length(data), times=(lengths(data)))
str(result)
# List of 50
 # $ 1 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ 1 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ 1 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ 1 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ 1 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ 2 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ 2 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ 2 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # etc
```

Shuffle

```
set.seed(1)
ans <- result[sample(1:50)]
str(ans)
# List of 50
 # $ 3 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ 4 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ 6 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ 9 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ 2 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ 9 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ 9 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # $ 6 : int [1:28, 1:28] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 # etc
```

Comment: This is great! however I am trying the same thing with lists being of different length. `names(res1) <- rep(1:10, each=lengths(trainData))` Something like this doesn't work :/

Comment: See my edit to try to handle your comment. `names(result) <-
 rep(1:length(data), times=(lengths(data)))` might work for you